# Minecraft-Lapis Luzuli Drop Distribution

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ignoring Fortune I-III, Lapis Luzuli ore drops 4-8 pieces of Lapis when mined with a stone or better pickaxe. Does anybody know the exact drop distribution for getting either 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 pieces?

Comment: Do you mean what is the probability that you will drop 4,5,6,7 or 8 pieces?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poor wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore) has an article about it.

You can obtain Lapis pieces at the following rates:

> 4 1⁄5
> 5   1⁄5
> 6   1⁄5
> 7   1⁄5
> 8   1⁄5

So ignoring Fortune levels the drop rates are completely equal with 20% each. Only using Fortune they will vary and even allow higher drops up to 32 pieces.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like I forgot to check that article. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.